# Jquery UI dialog get parameter value in code behind

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am trying to get parameter value from JQuery UI dialog in code behind page. I am getting 'undefined' message. Could you please suggest?

### Main.aspx

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $dialog = $('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 500,
            height: 600,
            zIndex: 40000
        });
    });
    function ShowGraph() {
        var url = $("#hidMainURL").val();
        $("#dialog")
        .data('param_1', url)
        .load('Graph.aspx');
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    }
```

### Graph.aspx

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var my_data = $("#dialog").data('param_1');
        $("#hidGetURL").val(my_data);
         alert(my_data);
 </script>
```

Comment: Can you include your html?

Answer (score 0):

It's not nice to load javascript like that - within an html page that is appended with ajax.

My first guess is that your Graph.aspx -> $("#dialog") doesn't find your #dialog.

Try console.log($("#dialog").length) at Graph.aspx.

I don't know what it is you're trying to accomplish here, but you should really try using json instead of load("stuff.aspx") that includes javascript.

Another thought:

If by any chance `ShowGraph` is called before `$(document).ready(function () {`,  then there's no jQuery UI dialog initiated!

Hope it's helpfull. Don't have time to dig into it fully.